# Prevent Jupyter Notebooks from changing the cwd

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-console

My folder structure is set out like this:

```
- project/
  - notebooks/
    - notebook1.ipynb
  - src/
    - module1.py
    - __init__.py
  - data/
    - data.csv
```

Such that I can separate my source code from the actual analysis.  I would like to be able to import modules from `src` and use them in `notebook1`, however whenever I open `notebook1`, Jupyter decides to change my working directory to be inside `notebooks`.

This makes my imports harder to maintain as I'd have to import things relatively to Jupyter's whim - is there any way I can fix the `cwd` such that it is always `project`, no matter what file I have open?

I have looked through the docs and my `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`, file but have found nothing that could help me.

EDIT: I'd like to not have to use `os.chdir` or `cd` at the top of every script.

Thanks for any help

Comment: so `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ''` from the config file doesn't do what you want?

Comment: That just changes the directory that the server loads into. With the structure above, it would load jupyter in the `notebooks` directory, so I'd still have to go up a level to get at `src`.

Comment: If you are using VSCode with the jupyte extension, there is a setting for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65683620/4050510

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you mean `cwd`, `pwd` is the shorthand for `print working directory`, whereas `cwd` is the shorthand for `current working directory`. Essentially, the `pwd` prints the `cwd`. Just a minor terminology issue there!

Secondly, you could always manually change the directory yourself at the top of the notebook:

```
import os
os.chdir("../")  # or manually specify project - whichever you prefer
```

I don't think there's any way to change the default behaviour automatically though - perhaps opening an issue on the notebook git repo would be a good idea? https://github.com/jupyter/notebook

Comment: Hah thanks for the `pwd` comment. I'd got that from some incorrect lecture [notes](!) that stated it was "Present working directory" - will amend. Regarding the actual answer, this is similar to my back up which was just to use the magic `cd` which works without any imports, but it's still not as neat as I'd like. I'll open an issue.