# countrycode package TypeError: 'module' object is not callable - Error shows wrong temp file: AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_

Tags: python, spyder

I know this has been asked elsewhere, but none of the solutions seem to be working.

I am trying to call the countrycode package (https://pypi.org/project/countrycode/).

Here is some test code:

```
from countrycode import countrycode
countrycode(codes=['Algeria', 'United States'], origin='country_name', target='iso3c')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_26092\2392981478.py", line 2, in <module>
    countrycode(codes=['Algeria', 'United States'], origin='country_name', target='iso3c')

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I see that the module call seems to be pointing at `"C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_26092\2392981478.py"`. When I look for this file on my system, I can't find it.

Searching around I see that some people have had problems with `Jupyter` notebooks setting the working directory as a temp folder that has a similar path: [Current working directory for jupyter notebook sets to temp folder in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59205268/current-working-directory-for-jupyter-notebook-sets-to-temp-folder-in-vscode)

I am using `Spyder`, running it within `Anaconda` - via which I installed countrycode using pip3.

I can't work out what the issue is. `os.getcwd()` returns the correct working directory. Further `print(countrycode)` appears to point to the correct module location: `<module 'countrycode.countrycode' from 'C:\\Users\\NAME\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\countrycode\\countrycode.py'>`. When I look at that `countrycode.py` file it seems to contain all the correct information.

I am assuming that somewhere some variable got created (in another script nothing here is named countrycode, and I have restarted) that is pointing to the Temp folder. But I can't work out how to make the module call point to the correct place - especially when the print call seems to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this package is not well supported, and its documentation on PyPI is inaccurate. I was able to get this working by updating the import statement to look one level deeper in the package:

```py
from countrycode.countrycode import countrycode

print(
  countrycode(
    codes=['Algeria', 'United States'], 
    origin='country_name', target='iso3c'
  )
)
```

Unfortunately the [GitHub for this package](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/pycountrycode) does not appear to still be live, so I cannot provide with certainty further details as to why the additional layer works.

Comment: This works. Thank you. This appears to be the package author: https://github.com/vincentarelbundock. I'll reach out pointing them to this page to see if they have thoughts. Could I ask how you knew from the file structure to try and look one level deeper. The structure seems to go `countrycode\\countrycode.py`. Was it just a guess or did something make you think to look?

Comment: @MorisseyJ Since the error made mention that the `countrycode` variable was still referring to a module object, I guessed that there may be a function by the same name stored in that module!

Comment: For anyone following up on this question. I contacted the author of the R package that this is a clone of. He indicated the python package is abandoned/dead (https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode/issues/318).